# C++ : Find pairs in an integer array whose sum is equal to 10 in linear time

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am practicing `C++` and having trouble doing this in linear time:

```
// Find pairs in an integer array whose sum is equal to 10 (bonus: do it in linear time)
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    using std::vector;

    std::vector<int> foo = {1,2,4,3,1,3,1,4,5,15,5,2,3,5,4};

    int i = 0;

    int j = foo.size() - 1;

    int a = 0, b = 0;

    while (i < j) {
        a = foo[i], b = foo[j];
        std::cout << a << " " << b << "\n";
        if ( a + b == 10) {break;}
        else if (a + b < 10) { i++;}
        else if (a + b > 10) { j--;}
    }

    std::cout << "a = " << a << " and b = " << b << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

This incorrectly prints `a = 15 and b = 5`

Comment: probably because `i < j` was no longer true. i is equal to 9 (thus a is equal to 15) and j is equal to 9 as well (thus b, because of previous loop, is equal to 5) when this happens

Comment: This solution seems to assume the vector is sorted.

Comment: Use a boolean array as a helper that detects if a number has already been "seen".  Don't know if I should post this as an answer, since this looks like homework.

Comment: You can iterate over the vector and store the index of each value in an array in the position of that value. You can then check if a given value's complement was previously found and obtain it's index, providing you with the indices of the pair.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie It is not homework.  I found this question on reddit https://www.reddit.com/r/cscareerquestions/comments/20ahfq/heres_a_pretty_big_list_of_programming_interview/

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux correct, I was just thinking that I should sort this vector.  I need to lookup how to sort an std::vector

Comment: @SamHammamy There is no known general sorting algorithm that is linear in time complexity. For future reference, you can use [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort).

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I found this std::sort(foo.begin(), foo.end());

Comment: @SamHammamy That is not linear time complexity, the documentation specifically states that it is `O(N·log(N))`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux OK I need to re-read your previous explanation and update.  Thanks

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux , that is not accurate. There is no binary comparison based algorithm that is "faster" than n*log(n). but if the numbers are in a known range you can convert their representation to binary and use radix sort

Comment: `stable_sort(foo.begin(), foo.end(), [](int a, int b) {return a < b; });`

Comment: You should have constraint of the given array, as sorted array or array of unsigned int to be able to do it in linear time.

Comment: @SamHammamy -- There is no need to sort this array.  Do as I stated, with what FrançoisAndrieux mentioned.  It takes a helper array to do this in linear time.  BTW, what should the answer be in your example?  Is it `5, 5` listed twice?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: It is [Counting_sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I made up the numbers  myself and thought yes it should be `5, 5`

Comment: @SamHammamy -- Have a "seen" array that is all 0 (or false).  Subtract each number in your original array from your target (which is 10).  Now go look into your "seen" array at that position.  If that position is marked as "seen", i.e. 1 or `true`, then that is a pair that matches.  Mark the "seen" array `true` at the index that is the same as the original number you just tested.  Rinse and repeat.  I think you should do this with pencil and paper first -- it is a very simple method.

Comment: Are negative values allowed?

Comment: unsorted_map should also provide you a linear time solution (on average)